# Lambda Async invocation throws errors, synchronous invocation works fine

Tags: php, lambda, aws-lambda, guzzle

I have the following code:

```html
<?php
echo('Success');

//Setup the API
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\Lambda\LambdaClient;

//Login to the Dynamo DB
$client = LambdaClient::factory(array(
'version' => 'latest',
  'region'  => 'us-east-1',
  'credentials' => array(
    'key' => 'My Key',
    'secret'  => 'My Secret',
  )
));

$rawdata = file_get_contents('php://input');

//echo("Raw Data:");
//echo($rawdata);

$client->invoke([
 'FunctionName' => 'LocationUpdate',
 'InvocationType' => 'Event',
 'Payload' => $rawdata
]);
```

When I run the code, without the invocation type, it works great. However when I go to run it with the invocation type being Event or DryRun, it does not work and instead throws the following errors. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Guzzle\Common\Exception\RuntimeException: Unable to parse response body into JSON: 4 in /var/www/html/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Response.php:861
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/LocationVisitor/Response/JsonVisitor.php(22): Guzzle\Http\Message\Response-&gt;json()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/OperationResponseParser.php(134): Guzzle\Service\Command\LocationVisitor\Response\JsonVisitor-&gt;before(Object(Guzzle\Service\Command\OperationCommand), Array)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/OperationResponseParser.php(86): Guzzle\Service\Command\OperationResponseParser-&gt;visitResult(Object(Guzzle\Service\Description\Parameter), Object(Guzzle\Service\Command\OperationCommand), Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Response))
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Command/DefaultResponseParser.php(39): Guzzle\Service\Command\OperationResponseParser-&gt;handleParsing(Object(Guzzle\Serv in <b>/var/www/html/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Message/Response.php</b> on line <b>861</b><br />
```

Comment: what is inside `$rawdata`? And why are you declaring `$contxt` and not using?

Comment: Context is left over from some example code I got a long time ago. (whoops!), and raw data is the php input. I am testing with the following `{"Serial":"GP40ovf9","Lat":"34.0","Lon":"-84","SoC":"100","Accuracy":"8.0"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and downloaded the PHAR lambda file instead of using the antiquated technique (guzzle) that I was using before, and it now works perfectly.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/installation.html